# Is Windows Linux based

Tags: linux, windows

Is Windows Linux based? Because I cannot find a stack exchange site for Windows. If there is not sit for Windows can anybody explain how to request a site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows and Windows-related questions, not Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 5):

No. (Modern) Windows is [VMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS)-based (or rather, [VMS-"inspired"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Cutler)).

End-user questions about Windows can be posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).